# p not contained in div with float

Tags: css-float

I'm trying to fully comprehend a float issue. In the code below, when div1 is floated left div2 snaps underneath it as expected, except for the paragraph text. Why does the paragraph text extend below div1 when the divs are identical?

HTML

```
<div id="div1">
    <p>This is div1</p>
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <p>This is div2</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float:left;
}

#div2  {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px black solid;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u9nugwbg/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need ta moke `position:absolute;` in div1

The code

```css
#parent {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}

#div1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float:left;
    position:absolute; <!--Make position:absolute-->
}

#div2  {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px black solid;
    

}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

<div id="div1">
    <p>This is div1</p>
</div>
    
<div id="div2">
    <p>This is div2</p>
</div>
    
</div><!--closes parent-->
```

If you remove div1 you'll see the `<p>` is in the yellow div.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to figure out why the p falls outside of the div. I know how to float the elements, just trying to wrap my brain around why the p isn't contained in the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You need ta moke foat:left; in div2. The Code:
    #div2
    {
     float: left;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: red;
     border: 1px black solid;
    }
    #parent {
     background-color: blue;
     width: 500px;
     height: 300px;
 }

#div1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float:left;
}
```